# Sorting then printing a vector in C++

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, iostream

Im trying to sort a vector of ints that i just randomly came up with and print it when its been sorted. However, when it prints, it is the same as the original unsorted vector. Is this occurring because my bricksort algorithm is incorrect or because my method of printing the vector is wrong? Any advice would be much appreciated.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int brickCount = 0;

void bricksort(vector <int> a)
{
    bool sorted = false;
    while( sorted != true )
    {
        sorted = true;
        for( int i = 1; i < a.size( ) - 1; i += 2 )
        {
            if( a[i] > a[i + 1] ) 
            {
                swap( a[i], a[i + 1] );
                brickCount++;
                sorted = false;
            }
        }
        for( int i = 0; i < a.size() - 1; i += 2 )
        {
            if( a[i] > a[i + 1] )
            {
                swap( a[i], a[i + 1] );
                brickCount++;
                sorted = false;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<int>::iterator pos;
    vector <int> nums = {9,8,5,6,76,3,84,234,1,4,6,4,345,54,23,76,85,83,82,61};
    //vector <int> nnums = bricksort(nums);
    bricksort(nums);
    for (pos=nums.begin(); pos!=nums.end(); ++pos) 
    {
        cout << *pos << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl << "brickCount is: " << brickCount << endl;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to write your own sort? std::sort is efficient and correct:

  std::sort(a.begin(), a.end());

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are passing a copy of the vector to `bricksort`. Try changing the function signature to: `void bricksort(vector <int> &a)` to pass a reference instead.

Answer (score 3):

Try passing a reference of `vector<int>` to the function instead:

```
void bricksort(vector<int>&a)
```